# datetime not always getting set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC project. This project has a form which submits date times in the format `yy/mm/dd hh:mm`. The controller has a model binding to receive the form values.

The `datetime` properties are declared as follows:

```
public DateTime? aDate { get; set; }

public DateTime? bDate { get; set; }
```

Using Chrome Dev Tools, I have confirmed that the `DateTime` value always gets sent.
However, sometimes the `aDate`/`bDate` properties get set, and sometimes they do not.

I have not been able to observe any consistent behavior or pattern in the dates being sent which causes this. Sometimes one of them gets set and the other does not.

All other properties in the model always get set if their corresponding form element has a value.

What could be causing this?

Comment: *Don't* use that format. Use the ISO8601 format, the same format that Javascript uses. The format you used can be parsed in *any way* imaginable, especially since only two digits are used for a year. Who says that the first two digits are a year and not a *day*? Especially *today*, March 21st 2019? What does `21/03/19` mean? It's quite likely that the string sent to the application is invalid given the application's locale and the binder rejects it

Comment: Use [Date.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) in Javascript. In your HTML ensure you submit the value, not the text from whatever date picker you use. Check for example the documentation of the [<input type="date">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value) element. The format is `YYYY-MM-DD` for dates

Comment: I tried this
i used the following format string - yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff
It did not work

Comment: Tried how? Where? What does the form code look like? How is it submitted?

Comment: My datepicker uses input type="text"
i have checked the strings being submitted and they are correct every time, even when the server fails to set the date

Comment: Use `type="date"` not text. It's not a date picker if the type is *text*, it's just a text input. Unless you use jQuery to display a date picker. Even then, you can retrieve the text and date values separately

Comment: As for "correct every time" you *assume*. With a 2-digit year there's no way to know wheter `21/03/19` is a date in 2019 or 2021.

Comment: it is using a jquery datepicker

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you have to mark DateTime as null able at model level. Just put it as DateTime. When date won't be provided at Form level, it would automatically be converted to equivalent of something you can deal at your back end side perfectly.

Comment: This is not something i want to do because without the nullable mark the dateTime gets a default which is displayed on my view (and i would need a hard coded if statement to stop this)

However i tried this suggestion anyway
and it did not work